# How to get Jenkins run same thing as "Inspect Code" does in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

As we all know that we have ***Android Lint*** which can be integrated with Jenkins and helps us to verify our code per commit or per day.

But Lint is not the exact same thing with what we can do in ***Android Studio -> Analyze -> Inspect Code***, which gives us a lot more warnings, and some of them are quite useful.

For instance, Unused Symbols, we may sometimes change the entire function which calls another and in the new implementation, we forget to make this call. If the target function belongs to the same file then you may notice that tiny yellow line, or you may not. What if it belongs to another file and the changed function was the only user of it?

Is there anyway to either make Lint be able to fire those warnings, or make Jenkins be able to run this "Inspect Code", collect results and break build when necessary? Doing this would be more efficient and reliable because we can't guarantee that everyone in the team is always run inspection locally.

Comment: Yes for sure it is possible. Have you tried things like https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/android-lint/ ?

Comment: @AntonisRadz thanks, but I don't think a Jenkins publisher plugin makes Android Lint be able to detect Unused Symbols, does it?

Comment: You can define your own lint rules in project and use that rules in Jenkins https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint

Comment: hi @AntonisRadz, again, thanks! I am not sure if it is me overlooked something but AFAIK lint only detects unused resources (in xml files) but does not detect unused symbols (in java/kotlin files), it is not about how to custom the rules of Lint.